# To show that $f(\cup_{i\in I}X_i)=\cup_{i\in I} f(X_i)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am working on my second-year multivariable calculus problem set (not an assignment), and I am stuck at a proof in basic Topology.
Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ be a map of sets, and let $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$ be an indexed collection of subsets of $A$. Show that $$f(\cup_{i\in I}X_i)=\cup_{i\in I} f(X_i)$$
My proof:
Let $u\in f(\cup_{i\in I}X_i)$.
Then there exists some $x\in X_i\subseteq \cup_{i\in I}X_i$ such that $f(x)=u$.
So $u\in f(X_i)$
Since $f(X_i)\subseteq \cup_{i\in I}f(X_i)$, $u\in\cup_{i\in I}f(X_i)$.

Now let $v\in\cup_{i\in I}f(X_i)$.
Then $\exists f(X_i)$ such that $v\in f(X_i)$. (Incorrect)
Then there exists some $x\in \cup_{i\in I}X_i$ such that $f(x)=v$.
Hence, $v\in f(\cup_{i\in I}X_i)$

I don't know why, but I think there is something wrong with my proof.
Can someone please enlighten me

Comment: If $f$ maps sets to sets, you can't simply let $f$ map elements of these sets.

Comment: In the second part of your proof there's a small typo, $v \in f(X_i)$ implies that there exists some $x$ in $X_i$ and hence in the union (it is really not a typo but if this is one of your first problems this way it is instructive to do them carefully).

Comment: Ok, I see, but I just don't have any other intuitions for this proof. Thank you Klaramun for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y\in f(\bigcup_{i}X_i)$ then there is an $x\in\bigcup_{i}X_i$ such that $y=f(x)$. In particular, there is an $i$ such that $x\in X_i$, and thus $f(x)\in f(X_i)\subset \bigcup_{i}f(X_i)$.

Reciprocally, if $y\in \bigcup_{i}f(X_i)$, there is an $i$ such that $y\in f(X_i)$, and thus, there is an $x\in X_i$ s.t. $y=f(x)$. In particular, $x\in \bigcup_{i}X_i$ and thus $y\in f(\bigcup_{i}X_i)$.

Comment: Does the proof really need to point out that particular $i$. Can't I just say there is a $X_i$ such that $y\in f(X_i)$

Comment: To say : "there is a $X_i$ such that $x\in X_i$" is equivalent at "there is an $i$ such that $x\in X_i$", therefore you can just say "there is a $X_i$ such that $y\in f(X_i)$. :-)

Comment: Then, is there any difference between my first part of proof and yours? I just can't tell, even though I think that yours are making much more sense.

Comment: It would be better to say: there is an $x\in \bigcup_{i}X_i$ such that $u=f(x)$, and thus, there is an $X_i$ such that $u=f(x)$. Therefore $u\in f(X_i)\subset \bigcup_{i}f(X_i)$. (the wrong thing is to write $f(X_i)\in \bigcup_{i}f(X_i)$ instead of $f(X_i)\subset \bigcup_{i}f(X_i)$. But excepted this point, it's correct. The second part of the proof, is really confusing... Moreover, $\exists f(X_i)$ is not very nice. In this case, it would be better to say that there is an $i$ such that $v\in f(X_i)$.